# 301 redirect but change URL to all lower case in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to set up a 301 redirect in Apache to change the case of the original address before redirecting. So for example if someone enters:

```
www.website1.com/UsErOfMiXedCase
```

it should forward to

```
www.website2.com/userofmixedcase
```

Would this be a redirect or would it need to be a rewrite? I'm not fussed about individual page forwarding (eg `www.website2.com/userofmixedcase/whatever.php`) - just `www.website1.com/whatever`.

Thank you in advance,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the rewrite map using [Apache's internal **tolower** function](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int). This can only be done in vhost or server config, and will result in an error if you try to put these directives in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

Then, in your htaccess file, you can use something like this **above any rewrite rules you already have**. The redirect rules must be before whatever rules you may have that does routing:

```
# check that the lower case version of the URI is different than the unchanged URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%1}::%1 !^(.*)::\1$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ http://www.website2.com/${lowercase:$1} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect a request like `http://www.website1.com/UsErOfMiXedCase` to `http://www.website2.com/userofmixedcase`, thus replacing the URL in the browser's address bar with the one that's all lowercase. Note that it won't affect URLs with multiple path nodes, e.g. `http://www.website1.com/SoMe/PathName/UsErOfMiXedCase`. If you want it to affect all requests including ones that have multiple paths/subdirectories, then you need to change this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to use `mod-rewrite`  for this. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://website2.com/$1 [NC]
```

That is a very general rule, so anything after the leading slash will be lower case. You may want to only do the lower case for specific portions of URL, but I cannot speak to that.

You probably should eyeball the [Apache mod-rewrite documentation about the NC flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) about this as well.

hth!